# Try to reach 2nd table 7th row 1st td using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to reach 2nd table 7th row 1st td in the div.

I tried

```
$('#WebPartWPQ1 table:first table:first tr:nth-child(6) td:first').html('test')
```

but it's not showing anything

```
<div id='WebPartWPQ1'>
  ....
  ....
  <table>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>
                ....
                .....
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    ...
                    <tr> //7th row
                       <td> //1st td
                          <h3>
                            <nobr>
                                 This value has to change
                            </nobr>
                          </h3>
                        </td>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: `:nth-child(6)` use 7 it satart with 1 as `:nth-child(7)`

Comment: if you could give a class to it. Then it would have been much easier rather than searching by indexes. Then we could target directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

> Description: Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent.
>
> index: The index of each child to match, starting with 1, the string even or odd, or an equation ( eg. :nth-child(even), :nth-child(4n) )

1. `:nth-child()`  starts with 1 change `:nth-child(6)` to `:nth-child(7)`.
2. `$('#WebPartWPQ1 table table tr:nth-child(7) td:first').html('test')` use this selector.

Comment: @james include the correct html mark up or just use `table table`

Answer (score 0):

use this ::

here is [https://jsfiddle.net/shantaram/fvznopns/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/shantaram/fvznopns/1/)

You have used `html('test')`, to get containing html you need to use `html()`

`$('.wrap table').find('table tr:nth-child(7) td:first').html("TEXT")`

OR

`$('.wrap table').find('table tr:nth-child(7) td:first').text("TEXT")`

Comment: My table is inside the first table (it is not 2nd table inside div)

Comment: in which row of first table ?

Answer (score 0):

i think we can do it like jQuery `eq()` selector , The result of this call is a gray background for item 7. **Note** that the supplied index is zero-based, and refers to the position of the element within the jQuery object, not within the DOM tree.

```
$(function(){

  $('table tr td > table').find('tr').eq(6).addClass('selected');

});
```

```js
$(function(){
 
$('table tr td > table').find('tr').eq(6).addClass('selected');
 
});
```

```css
table {
 border:1px solid #000;
}
td {
 width:200px;
 border:1px solid #d1d1d1;
}
.selected {
  background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
 <tr>
     <td>ad</td>
        <td>ad</td>
        <td>
         <table>
            <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td>ad</td>
                    <td>ad</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>ad</td>
                    <td>ad</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>ad</td>
                    <td>ad</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>ad</td>
                    <td>ad</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>ad</td>
                    <td>ad</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>ad</td>
                    <td>ad</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>ad</td>
                    <td>ad</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>    
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping through your rows then there is a better solution.

You give row a `class` and a `data` attribute to target directly as -

```
<tr class='myRow' data-index='7'> //guessing you are getting index while looping through
```

Then you query directly as, will return you row -

```
var row = $('.myRow').data('index',7)
```

Certainly, there are many possible ways too.